# Leibniz-rule for Lie-derivative: special case for 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

I have to prove the following statement for a 1-form $\alpha\in\Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M})$ and two vector fields $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$:

$$\mathrm{d}\alpha (X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y))-Y(X(\alpha))-\alpha([X,Y])$$

For this proof I have to use the general formula

$$\mathcal{L}_{u}(\omega(v_{1},\dots,v_{n})) = (\mathcal{L}_{u}\omega)(v_{1},\dots,v_{n}) + \omega(\mathcal{L}_{u}v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{n}) + \omega(v_{1},\mathcal{L}_{u}v_{2},v_{3},\dots,v_{n})+\dots 
 +\omega(v_{1},\dots,\mathcal{L}_{u}\dots,v_{n})$$

for a k-form $\omega\in\Omega^{k}(\mathcal{M})$ and vector fields $u,v_{1},\dots,v_{n}\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$.

Using this formula for my special case of a 1-form $\alpha$ I received

$$\mathcal{L}_{X}(\alpha(Y))=(\mathcal{L}_{X}\alpha)(Y)+\alpha(\mathcal{L}_{X}Y)$$

Using:

(1) $\alpha(\mathcal{L}_{X}Y) = \alpha([X,Y])$

(2) $\alpha(X)\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{L}_{X}(\alpha(Y))=X(\alpha(Y))$

(3) $(\mathcal{L}_{X}\alpha)(Y) = (\mathrm{d}i_{X} + i_{X}\mathrm{d})\alpha(Y) = \mathrm{d}\alpha(X,Y) + i_{X}\mathrm{d}\alpha(Y)$

I get the formula:

$$\mathrm{d}\alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y)) - i_{X}\mathrm{d}\alpha(Y) -\alpha([X,Y]) $$

So to finish the proof, I have to show that $i_{X}\mathrm{d}\alpha(Y) = Y(X(\alpha))$....But I can`t see why this is the case...

Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you!

Comment: You'd better start by repairing #3.  $\mathscr L_X \alpha = \iota_X(d\alpha) + d(\iota_X\alpha)$. This is not remotely what you wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check the formula you are trying to prove. I think it is
$$\mathrm{d}\alpha (X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y))-\underline{Y(\alpha(X))}-\alpha([X,Y]),$$
since $X(\alpha)$ doesn't make sense.

Next as Ted Shifrin said, you should check your computation for (3). You should do
$$(\mathcal L_X \alpha)(Y) = [(\mathrm d i_X + i_X \mathrm d)\alpha] (Y) = [\mathrm d (i_X\alpha)](Y) + (i_X\mathrm d\alpha)(Y).$$
I put extra brackets to help clarify the order of operations.

For the first term, $i_X\alpha = \alpha(X)$ is a smooth function. Then using $\mathrm d f(X) = Xf$ for any function $f$,
$$[\mathrm d (i_X\alpha)](Y) = [\mathrm d(\alpha(X)](Y)=Y\alpha(X).$$
For the second term, $\mathrm d\alpha$ is a 2-form. Using $i_X\omega(Y) = \omega(X,Y)$ for any 2-form $\omega$,
$$(i_X\mathrm d\alpha)(Y) = \mathrm d\alpha(X,Y).$$